# Mongoose middleware not running in my Next.js app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I have Mongoose middleware in my app to handle the `updatedAt` action. Here's the code for that:

```
ExampleSchema.pre("updateOne", function (next) {
    this.updatedAt = () => Date.now() as Date;
    next();
});
```

However, after refreshing in Mongoose it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's the relevant parts of my Schema

```
const ExampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: () => Date.now(),
    },
    updatedAt: Date,
});
```

## Edit 8/21/23:

From my response to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76942728/19019306).

> Adding a console log in the middleware function also does nothing. So the middleware likely isn't running

Comment: Show the debugging details.